# ListView's SelectedIndex wrong value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem with the value returned by ListView's `SelectedIndex`. The function looks like this:

```
private void ChangeCableStatus_DoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = tableOfCables.SelectedIndex;
    if (index == -1) // selected empty entry
    {
        return;
    }

    var selectedEntry = tableOfCables.SelectedItems[0] as Cable;
    var node1 = selectedEntry.Node1;
    var port1 = selectedEntry.Port1;
    var node2 = selectedEntry.Node2;
    var port2 = selectedEntry.Port2;

    cableCloud.Config.Cables.FirstOrDefault(cable =>
        cable.Node1.Equals(node1) && cable.Node2.Equals(node2) && cable.Port1.Equals(port1) &&
        cable.Port2.Equals(port2)).Working ^= true;

    tableOfCables.Items.Refresh();
}
```

So, when I double click on any entry in the table, it should change the status from "true" to "false" or vice versa.

[image]
After double clicking for the first time, it works fine and the status in the selected index changes to "false". But then, no matter on what entry I click, it changes the status of the previously selected entry from "false" to "true". For instance: I double click on the first row, it changes status from "true" to "false", then I select the 5th row, double click, it changes status of the previously selected entry from "false" to "true", completely ignoring selected row. And then, I double click on, let's say, 2nd row, it changes its status from "true" to "false" and the story repeats itself.
I checked with debugger and every 2nd double click the `SelectedIndex` value does not change. How to fix this?

```
<ListView x:Name="tableOfCables" Margin="10,10,10,10" PreviewKeyDown="ChangeFontSizeKeyboard" PreviewMouseWheel="ChangeFontSizeMouse" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" AlternationCount="2">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex"  Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex"  Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#f8f8f8" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ChangeCableStatus_DoubleClick" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        </Style>
                    </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Node1" Width="85" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Node1}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Port1" Width="85" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Port1}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Node2" Width="85" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Node2}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Port2" Width="85" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Port2}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Working" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Working}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Max BW" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MaxBandwidth}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Free BW" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FreeBandwidth}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

If anyone is interested, the whole project is here (startup argument is `./Resources/cloud.cloudconfig`): https://drive.google.com/file/d/11e84tqgTqXJ1hsYCQOTmA4prV0r9kQNW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try to handle `MouseDoubleClick` event of a `GridView`

Comment: @SantaXL I debugged your code and I checked there is no change in Index when double click event is raised. I guess there is other event/method which is causing to make the Control's index as 0.

Comment: Can elaborate what ChangeFontSizeKeyboard do?

Comment: I recommend you look at mvvm. Bind the selecteditem, use a mousebinding for the double click. One problem you might have here is the event is raised before the selectedindex has changed.

Comment: @itaiy when ctrl and "-"/"+" are pressed at the same time, it decreases/increases font's size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your source, this happens because you override the hashcode manually in your Cable class, remove this block problem wil solved:

```
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hashCode = (Node1 != null ? Node1.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Port1.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (Node2 != null ? Node2.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Port2.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Working.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ MaxBandwidth;
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it didn't help. I added the link to the whole project (it is less than 300 LoC)

Comment: that source needs access

Comment: edit: sorry, I forgot to set the access to the file. Now it should be downloadable

Comment: thank you, I had no idea this could affect this part of the code

Comment: when you override the hashcode container cannot find real item from listview because the point of item changs manualy